# NodeJS App got SQL connection time out after deployment

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am following the example on this link to build a NodeJS
web server using Googl Cloud and SQL database.

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql

I added my home network address to authorized network of 
Google SQL. The web server runs well locally, can read and write
Google SQL database.

But after deploy the example to cloud server,
webpage is loaded fine, but all SQL queries get error
as "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT"

Source code is avaialbel at;
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/tree/master/2-structured-data

It's just really frustrating that a simple step by step tutorial
is not working as expected.

From home I can use MySQL client to connect to Google SQL server (IP address is known from Google Clourd Console).

But from Cloud Shell (Launched from top right corner of Google Cloud Console), MySQL client also could not connect to the same Google SQL server.
PING the IP address does work.